# Can't open LibreOffice

Tags: 12.10, libreoffice

I can't open LibreOffice anymore, neither Writer nor Calc.

1. If I try it from the launcher, the icons flash a few times and then
   stop. The LibreOffice start window emerges for about one second and
   then disappears.
2. If I open Nautilus and click on any document assigned to
   LibreOffice, the LibreOffice start window emerges for about one
   second and then disappears.
3. When trying it from the terminal with `libreoffice --writer`, for
   example, I see the same behavior and the following error message:

   ```
   [Java framework] Error in function createSettingsDocument (elements.cxx).
   javaldx failed! 
   Warning: failed to read path from javaldx
   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'com::sun::star::uno::RuntimeException'
   ```

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this discussion](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=93168), if it applies to you as well (first part):

> The permissions are:
>
> ```
> drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Mar  6 13:58 .config
> ```
>
> Only folder in `~/` owned by `root` I might add.
>
> ---
>
> that being the case
>
> ```
> sudo chown -vR matt:users /home/matt/.config
> ```
>
> Your user should own .config within your home folder

Comment: But won't the permissions be correct in the first place? Anyway, OP can check if there is something like this: `drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Mar  6 13:58 .config`. Spooky if it is! (Mine is `drwx------ 28 vasa1 vasa1   4096 Jan 13 15:10 .config/
`)

Answer (score 1):

I one had this problem after updating from ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04. After reinstalling libreoffice it worked. The problem then returned and or I had other issues like the program hanging up the whole system and I had to reboot.

I solved this by trial and error by changing the display driver.